# calling python from R with instant output to console

Tags: python, r

I run python scripts from R using the R command:

```
system('python test.py')
```

But my print statements in test.py do not appear in the R console until the python program is finished. I would like to view the print statements as the python program is running inside R. I have also tried `sys.stdout.write()`, but the result is the same. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code for test.py:

```
import time

for i in range(10):
  print 'i=',i
  time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: it's working fine for me on Linux and R 3.0.1 - I see output as it's being generated

Comment: I (the original poster) am running it on MacOS

Comment: On Windows 7, I see the same behavior as the OP.  If it were R code running, I'd put in a call to `flush.console()`, but of course that doesn't help here.

Comment: You can use rPython R package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested on Windows 8 with R v3.0.1

Simply right click on the r console then **untick/unselect** the `Buffered Output` option (See image below). Now execute your code you shall see the output of `print` statements!

[image: image-file]

Update:

I forgot to mention that I also needed to add `sys.stdout.flush()` after the `print` statement in the python file.

```
import time
import sys

for i in range(5):
    print 'i=',i
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Also if you select the `Buffered Output` option then when you left click on the r console while your script is executing you shall see the output. Keep clicking and the output is shown. :)

Comment: @user3433489 If my answer solved your problem then please accept it by clicking on the tick mark on the left side. It helps other users to know that this question is solved and this solution really works. It also provides you some rep points and me too.:)